# Is there some way to change the default setting from All Files in the file upload dropdown?

Tags: php, forms, image, upload, popup

I'm currently building a file upload method for a client that's going to be used by small children, so we're trying to eliminate as much room for error as possible. Is there a way I can change the default setting of the file upload dropdown from All Files to the filetypes we're allowing on the page? We've already got measures in place to keep users from uploading non-allowed files, this is just to make it extra clear so users don't waste time accidentally selecting the wrong filetype. Example:

[image: file upload dropdown]

I'd like to have the field the arrow is pointing to automatically show, say, .jpg and .pdf instead of All Files, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the accept attribute of the input tag. So to accept only PNGs, JPEGs and GIFs you can use the following code:

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
```

Or simply:

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />
```

Note that this only hits the browser to accept this code. I. E. Opera and ie9 does not support this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `accept` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Limiting_accepted_file_types) on the `<input>` field:

```
<input type="file" … accept="image/png, image/gif">
```